# What version(s) of Infragistics NetAdvantage provides IGUltraGrid20.ocx?

Tags: infragistics, ocx, netadvantage

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all versions of Infragistics NetAdvantage released to date? I am looking specifically for versions providing the control IGUltraGrid20.ocx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PDF from the Infragistics site could be your answer.

http://download.infragistics.com/download/pubs/ProductLifeCycle.pdf

The latest version of the control was 2.01.60 released with the UltraSuite 3.02 dated March-2006.
It is officially retired and no more supported.
From the same document, the IGUltraGrid20.ocx version 2.01.25 was included in the NetAdvantage suite till the version 2005 v.2 and disappeared in next release 2005 v.3

Comment: Found another bit of info to share. It seems that exist also a NetAdvantage 2005 vol.3 FOR COM COMPONENTS separated from the NET only version.